# duplicate data in two table for record keeping design?

Tags: database, database-design

I am designing various databases for my company. I am having the concern of having duplication in the database because as far as i know, we must reduce duplication and keep the table normalized most of the time.

However, I am having this business requirement that the data recorded **must not** be updated all the time. for example,

I have three table
Medical Leave  |  Employee  | Position

Jane applied leave when she is executive
then she applied another leave when she is a Manager years later.

Then, admin has decided to change the position name of Executive(ID: 1) to Engineer (ID: 1)

The System should generate a report based on past position

```
07/03/2014 Jane Executive  
06/03/2017 Jane Manager
```

The system should not change the Executive to Engineer in the report.

the Current design of the Medical Leave table is

```
PK_ID, Leave Type, Leave Date, FK_EmployeeID, FK_PositionID, FK_PositionName
```

is the above is a bad design of the database or there is other way to handle this issue.

because if i use

```
PK_ID, Leave Type, Leave Date, FK_EmployeeID
```

the system will always query the latest position title but not the old position title.

or i will need to adopted Versioned Data concept for best practises?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a problem here. 
If table [position] is actually [positions] then  you can query for all the positions held by EmployeeID and then subquery the resulting list to get the leave data.

Nice example is here:

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Comment: hi i have rephrase my question

Comment: Jane applied leave when she is executive then she applied another leave when she is a Manager years later.
Then, admin has decided to change the position name of Executive(ID: 1) to Engineer (ID: 1)

The System should generate a report based on past position 

    07/03/2014 Jane Executive  
    06/03/2017 Jane Manager

The system should not change the Executive to Engineer in the report.

Comment: You still have positionID AND PostionName in the leave table to which you can index on EmployeeID + LeaveDate so if the position name changes you will see that.